# Combining Specific Rows based on WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I can't seem to find the solution to my problem. I have a database table that stores time clock punches :

[ID], [Status], [Date]

[Status] can be: "clock_in" or "clock_out"

[Date] can be 1 minute, 1 hour, 1 day, 1 week or 1 month apart

When I select the data, I need to select it so it pairs with the next row it finds ONLY and then moves on. My issue is my query is comparing every clock_in request with every clock_out request causing invalid data.

```
SELECT A1.staff_id, 
    A1.datetime AS check_in_at,
    A2.datetime AS check_out_at, 
    ROUND((TO_SECONDS(A2.datetime) - TO_SECONDS(A1.datetime)) / 60) AS total_time
    FROM
    staff_clock AS A1
    INNER JOIN staff_clock AS A2 
    ON A1.staff_id = A2.staff_id
    WHERE A1.status = 'clock_in' 
    AND A2.status = 'clock_out'
    AND DATE(A1.datetime) BETWEEN '2020-05-23 00:00:00' 
    AND '2020-06-01 00:00:00' 
    AND DATE(A2.datetime) BETWEEN '2020-05-23 00:00:00' 
    AND '2020-06-01 00:00:00' 
    AND A1.staff_id = '33'
    ORDER BY A1.datetime DESC
```

Example of the Query Results:

[image: Example Query Results]

Example of the Data:

[image: Data Example]

What I need the query to return is punch ID 121 paired with 137, and punch ID 248 paired with 257 (Every clock_in grabs the next entry of clock_out)

Thank you!!!!

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Latest Version of MySQL

Comment: 5.7 or 8.0? there's a huge difference...